# Safari iPhone - How to detect zoom level and offset?

Tags: iphone, safari

I looking for options on how to track user zooming and panning on a page when viewed in Safari on an iPhone.  Safari exposes move and gesture events, so theoretically I can keep a running tally of pan and zoom operations, but that seems like overkill since the browser must track that internally.

Is this information exposed through the Document Object Model?

Answer (score 28):

When you zoom in, `window.innerWidth` is adjusted, but `document.documentElement.clientWidth` is not, therefore:

```
var zoom = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
```

(I've tested iOS4, without `viewport` `<meta>`).

However, I wouldn't rely on it for anything important. DOM viewport sizes/pixel sizes in mobile browsers [are a complete mess](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/widths.html).

Comment: Thanks for that.  It's a hack, but it sounds like it might actually work, which is at least something.

Comment: Just pointing out here (so maybe one fewer doc run is needed) that `document.documentElement.clientWidth` does not include the scrollbars, while `window.innerWidth` does. Same for height.

Comment: Ignoring scrollbars, for Safari 10, its     var zoom = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.outerWidth;

Comment: I meant:   window.outerWidth / document.documentElement.clientWidth

Answer (score 3):

On Mobile Safari and Android, here is an accurate way to measure how much the page has been zoomed.

Try it here: http://jsbin.com/cobucu/3 - change zoom then click measure.

Technique is to add a top level div:

```
<body>
<div id=measurer style="position:absolute;width:100%"></div>
```

and use the calculation:

```
function getZoom(){
    return document.getElementById('measurer').offsetWidth / window.innerWidth;
}
```

The only problem is finding a tidy way to detect that the user has changed zoom (pinch, double tap, etc). Options:

- webkitRequestAnimationFrame: very reliable, but likely to cause jankiness if using animations (due to performance hit)
- setInterval: reliable but very ugly
- touch events: look for two fingers or
  double tap: ugly and maybe difficult to make 100% reliable
- window.onresize + window.onorientationchange + window.onscroll: simple but totally unreliable (Edit: and onscroll can cause performance problems in WKWebView or Mobile Safari 8 or greater).

PS: Windows Phone needs a different solution (pinch-zoom doesn't change the viewport - pinch-zoom on Windows has its *own* separate viewport that is not visible to javascript).

Edit: Android Visual Viewport resize and scroll events may help? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport#Events

Comment: Tested in an iPhone worked almost perfectly. The function did not detect the zoom in some occasions. Especially when doing big zoom-ins.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://tuvix.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html), zoom events (double tap) are not exposed, so I'm not sure how you can track this.

I do not believe this information is exposed through the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think things might have moved on a little since Steve's answer, as having a look at the content guide link he provided I can see a section on [Handling Multi-Touch Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW22) and also [Handling Gesture Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW23).

Haven't tried them yet but they look pretty promising.  I'll provide an update once I've checked them out and have a demo link available...

Comment: google fastflip (http://fastflip.googlelabs.com/) does it, so it's certainly possible

Answer (score 1):

I measure zoom this way (works on iOS only):

```
screenOrientedWidth = screen.width;
if (window.orientation == 90) {
    screenOrientedWidth = screen.height;
}
return screenOrientedWidth / window.innerWidth;
```

It doesn't depend of how wide content is.

However, in iOS Safari `window.innerWidth` isn't correct inside a `gestureend` handler. You should defer such calculation for later execution. In GWT, I use `scheduleDeferred`, but I can't say how to implement this in pure JavaScript.

Comment: This seems to work, in macOS Safari, for computing the amount of Page Zoom (i.e. zooming in and out with ⌘+ and ⌘-). However, it seems to always return 1 in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any elements with location:fixed this can get complicated, as the location:fixed coordinates are relative to the unzoomed window, where window coordinates are relative to the zoomed viewport. More info: [How to position a fixed-location element on IOS browser when zoomed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085998/how-to-position-a-fixed-location-element-on-ios-browser-when-zoomed/)