# How to keep the size of the div tags in the body of a page unaffected while zooming the page?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page in which the body contains a div tag. In side the div tag I have a table which contains some other div tags. When the I zoom the body the dropdown div tags should be restricted from zooming(or even if it is zoomed I want to bring it back to original size). The CSS for body is:

```
body {
    width:1000px;
    padding-top:100px;
    zoom: 1.165; -moz-transform: scale(1.165);
}
```

The code is shows below.

```
<body>
<!--end of button effect-->
<div class="type-road-form">
<h1></h1>
<hr>
<table>
<tr id="rd-type">
    <td height="70">
        <div class="drop-down">
          <select name="select-rd-type" id="select-rd-type">
<option>Select Road Type</option>
            <option>urban</option>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="sped-limit">
    <td height="70">
        <label>Speed Limit (mph)</label>
        <br>
        <div class="drop-down">
        <select id="Drop-Down-Speed" name="Speed Limit Selection">
        <option >Select Speed</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>30</option>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add width to your div, put the following in the stylesheet

```
div.type-road-form { width: 1000px; }
```

Btw you have an extra `</table>` just after `<body>` you will need to remove it.

Comment: I still face the same problem that the div tags are being re-sized when the body is zoomed

Comment: So does it solve your problem? I looked at other answers it seems like I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no good way of doing that. You can get more reference here:

[How to keep a <div> constant in size as the user zooms in and out on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117349/how-to-keep-a-div-constant-in-size-as-the-user-zooms-in-and-out-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

i think u can try to set your out most parent div with

```
style="position:relative"
```

this worked for me , i think this will be a proper solution , now all the child divs would be positioned accordingly and will not move.