# Can I change cascading style sheet while zooming browser

Tags: html, css

Can I change css property when browser zoom is change without js, how to solve this overlapping while zooming

[image]

Comment: Please post an example or demonstration on a site like jsFiddle instead of a low-resolution screenshot.

Comment: Is this for zooming in or out? Please post a fiddle as the link you have attached is of low quality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect page zoom change with jQuery in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163174/detect-page-zoom-change-with-jquery-in-safari)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var zoom = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var zoomNew = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
    if (zoom != zoomNew) {
        $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
        zoom = zoomNew
    }
});
```